delay module execution until EC2 userdata cp command completes
As part of my app rollout I need an EFS volume with files on it.  I spin up an EC2 instance and in the userdata function of the instance, I mount a source & destination EFS volume and copy over the needed files.  That process works fine, however the cp command doesn't complete in time for the next modules which spin up the app, so I need a delay.
I have tried depends_on and the time_sleep module to delay the next modules.  The depends_on doesn't wait long enough.  Also, the time_sleep module appears to cut off the execution of the EC2 userdata execution.  Whenever I use it, only part of the userdata script completes and the mounts/cp command never execute.
here is my userdata function:
#!/bin/bash
#ensure user data runs every start
exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1
mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/source-env
chmod -R 777 /home/ec2-user/source-env
mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2  ${efs_source_volume}:/ /home/ec2-user/source-env
+mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/${env_name}/${env_name}
chmod -R 777 /home/ec2-user/${env_name}
mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 ${efs_id}:/     /home/ec2-user/${env_name}
cp -R /home/ec2-user/source-env/* /home/ec2-user/${env_name}/${env_name}/
chmod -R 777 /home/ec2-user/${env_name}/

time_sleep module is quite simple (example code with actual names changed):
resource "null_resource" "efs_ec2_create" {}

resource "time_sleep" "wait_30_seconds" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.efs_ec2_create]

  create_duration = "30s"
}

resource "null_resource" "start_apps" { 
  depends_on = [time_sleep.wait_30_seconds]
}

